# Obtaining a site url with correct binding port dynamically

Tags: site-configuration, links

I have a situation where I need to obtain a link to the item at my site to use it in an e-mail notification. I currently do it like this: `var baseUrl = new Uri(Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl);`.
This method works for my local site instance, which has the following bindings:

```
Type | Host name | port
http |    foo    | 80 
https|    foo    | 443
```

I go to https://foo/, trigger my e-mail notification and the link I get in the e-mail is "https://foo/", so all is well. When debugging, `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` contains "https://foo:443".
However, our shared sandbox site is configured to be used as https://foo.bar:44305. The bindings there are as follows:

```
Type | Host name | port
http |    foo    | 80 
https|    foo    | 443
https|           | 8082
http |           | 8081
https|           | 44301
https|           | 44305
```

and while I use https://foo.bar:44305 to trigger e-mail to be sent, I receive "https://foo.bar:8081" in my e-mails.
If I add an extra binding

```
<... >
https|    foo    | 40443
```

to my local instance, I start getting "https://foo:40443" in the e-mails while triggering them from plain https://foo.

The alternative we tried is hard-coding the link to be used in `Web.config`. which obviously works, but the link is not resolved dynamically, so we have to always keep this in mind to change it before deploying to production, etc.
Is there actually a way to do this properly without hard-coding or messing up the bindings? I'm also very curious why `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` contains a seemingly random binding port.

**Update:** per @RichardSeal's advice I also tried to get this link via `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager`:

```
var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
var url = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
```

In this case I obtain a relative url, not a full url, i.e: `/en/sitecore/shell/foo/home/lookbook/sales/list`

Comment: Are you trying to get a link to your home page or another page on the site. Trying to work out why you are using `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` to build the link instead of the `LinkManager`

Comment: @RichardSeal There are several cases, but it's mostly about links to various Angular pages at the site, something like "https://foo:44305/sales/list/".

Comment: is `sales/list` a Sitecore item? Also - do the urls need to be full? can they be created as relative urls? Then you don't have to worry about the host

Comment: The link is to go into an email which is why they want them to be absolute.

Comment: @elellle - When faced with an issue like this in the past, we have had something akin to a PublishedHost setting, so we had absolute control over the host in the URL. This was set as a deployment variable so we never had to worry about editing it for production etc., much like a connection string.

Comment: @RichardSeal sorry, didn't think well about it, it actually is a Sitecore page. And yes, I need full urls - this is something I send out to users in e-mails so they could visit the site and check out a particular page. I tried out `LinkManager` and updated my question text.

Comment: @Kasaku thank you!  I guess this is something which makes most sense for the situation so far. Will do that unless the `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` mystery gets solved :)

Comment: how are your Sitecore site definitions defined??

Comment: @PeteNavarra it is like this: https://gist.github.com/epetrashen/cea8c54ba92ccb7a9983c000ae4c35aa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` is set in the `Globals.Load` function by calling `WebUtil.GetServerUrl(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, false)`.

The code for that is:

```
public static string GetServerUrl(Uri url, bool forcePort)
{
    if (url == (Uri) null)
        return string.Empty;
    string scheme = url.Scheme;
    string host = url.Host;
    string @string = url.Port.ToString();
    string str = string.Format("{0}://{1}", (object) scheme, (object) host);
    if (forcePort || @string != "80")
        str += string.Format(":{0}", (object) @string);
    return str;
}
```

So the ports are getting added because `GetServerUrl` adds the port any time the `Uri.Port` value is not `80`.

To make the `LinkManager` work, you need to make sure that in your site definition you have both the `targetHostName` and `scheme` set correctly. These can be setup in your standard deployment process:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <sites>
            <site name="foo" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
                  host="foo.com|other.foo.com"
                  ... other settings ...
                  targetHostName="foo.com"
                  scheme="https"
                  />
        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

With those set, calling the `LinkManager` with `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` set to true in the options should give you:

`https://foo.com/en/path/to/your/page`

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea on why the `Uri.Port` that is added not the same that the one I actually use? My problem with `Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl` is that I go to  `https://foo.bar:44305/whatever/page`, change it, and the users get an e-mail notification that contains a wrong port, i.e.: "Hey, `https://foo.bar:8081/whatever/page` was changed, check it out."

Comment: My guess would be that there is some internal redirection happening, possibly behind a load balancer. If the external port is 44305 to the LB, but the LB then hits the origin server at port 8081, the code will only see the 8081 port.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using config transformation, having different site urls for local build, qa build and production in my `Sitecore.config`, `Sitecore.QA.config`, etc.